# Cutting Edge to the Left Bottom

Tags: css

I have find that code but all in vain to put the cutting edge to the left bottom please help.
how can we put that corner to left bottom. i have been trying but all in vain

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3DXBE/)**

```
<div class="doc"></div>
```

CSS

```
.doc{
   position:relative;
   height:46px;
   width:28px;
}

.doc, 
.doc:before{
  background-color: #c40d12;
}

.doc:after{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px; 
  right:-9px;
  content:"";
  display:block;
  width:0px; 
  height:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border-bottom: 9px solid #c40d12;
  border-right: 9px solid transparent;
  background:transparent;
}
.doc:before{
  position:absolute;
  top:9px;
  right:-9px;
  content:"";
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
  width:9px; 
  height:37px;
}

.doc:hover, 
.doc:hover:before{
  background-color: #970101;
}
.doc:hover:after{
  border-bottom: 9px solid #970101;
}
```

Comment: Simple code using `clip` method http://jsfiddle.net/UDYd4/ , for the other corner http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/UDYd4/1/

Comment: and what for if we want to take it to left top?

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/UDYd4/2/

Comment: but it doesnt work properly when text in written inside it, but the code Vinod made is working, but dont know how to put that code to left top corner

Comment: using `clip` is very limited in dynamically responding to text change, I just saw you set fixed width and height for your div so my guess is it's OK to use `clip` here. It's just another approach I would like to share and can be used in some case. For the Vinod's  solution, of course it will be more dynamic, however you can try hovering on the transparent corner and see what happens. Perfectly it should not change the background-color when hovering on that corner.

Comment: if hovering on the transparent corner does not matter, there is a much more simpler solution here http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/UDYd4/3/ you can freely change the width and height, the top-left corner is always ensured to be *clipped* (not really clipped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following CSS rules overwriting existing one.

JSFiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/W5Hx9/

```
.doc{
   position:relative;
   height:46px;
   width:28px;
}

.doc, 
.doc:before{
  background-color: #c40d12;
}

.doc:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: -9px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 9px solid #c40d12;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
    background: transparent;
}

.doc:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 9px;
    left: -9px;
    content: "";
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 9px;
    height: 37px;
}

.doc:hover, 
.doc:hover:before{
  background-color: #970101;
}
.doc:hover:after{
  border-bottom: 9px solid #970101;
}
```

Comment: will give you +1 if you provide hover's too. :D

Comment: @Era : Are you talking about adding hover code in the solution provided?

Comment: yup. now its perfect +1

Comment: sorry but what if we want to take that cutting edge corner to left top??

Comment: To display the cutting edge corner to left top use the CSS code provided on this JSFiddile http://jsfiddle.net/vinoddalvi/4egjv/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit simpler solution: http://jsfiddle.net/W5Hx9/1/.

```
.doc{
   position:relative;
   height:46px;
   width:37px;
   background-color: #c40d12;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.doc:after{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px; 
  bottom: 0px;
  content:"";
  border-bottom: 9px solid #fff;
  border-right: 9px solid transparent;
}

.doc:hover {
  background-color: #970101;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had modified the `before` and `after` css like this

Working Code:[JSFIDDL](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/6aSLQ/14/)E